# How to get multilevel children

Tags: javascript, jquery

On submit of class `post_alternate_category_name` I need to make value of input element `alternate_category` empty and I need to set the text of label `.ermsg` as `saving..`. The code which I have written is not working:

```
<form method="POST" class="form-horizontal post_alternate_category_name">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Alternate name</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input class="m-wrap large alternate_category" name="alternate_category" type="text" value="">
      <button type="submit" class="btn blue">Add</button>
      <label class="ermsg" style="color: red"></label>
      <input type="hidden" name="category_id" value="1">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Jl3DOrLd0clH5cv17I5JQumqFtJzV8uNjblIZGu3">
  </div>
</form>
```

```js
$('.post_alternate_category_name').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "someurl",
    data: "somedata",
    beforeSend:function() {
      $(this).children('.control-group').children('.controls').children('.ermsg').val('Saving');
      $(this).find('.ermsg').html("");
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $(this).children('.control-group').children('.controls').children('input[name="alternate_category"]').val('');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: In method `beforeSend` and `success` method  _this_ doesn't refers to `FORM` it refers to `window`. Use `context: this,` option of `$.ajax()` and your code should work

Comment: @Satpal ok, what does it refer to ? and how can i then access input element "alternate_category" ?

Comment: A label does not have a `.val()`.

Comment: Please learn how to use jQuery selectors.

Comment: I resolved the issue using var self = $(this)

Answer (score 0):

a) I need to make value of input element "alternate_category" empty.

```
$('input[name="alternate_category"]').val('');
```

b) I need to set the text of label ".ermsg" as "saving.."

```
$('.ermsg').html("saving..");
```

Comment: using `.text()` instead of `html()` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> .find() function to get all children inside element.
>   [jQuery find](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

Instead of using multiple ".children()" methods, you can reset and update values directly. See code below. Place it anywhere you like.

```
$('.post_alternate_category_name').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('input[name=alternate_category').val('');
    $('label.ermsg').text(''Saving...);
)};
```